# UIButton checkbox

Tags: iphone, ios5, uibutton

I have 6 UIButtons which have been generated in the following code:

```
int count = 0;
    for (int i= 0; count<6; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<1&&count<6; j++) {
            followbutn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            followbutn.frame = CGRectMake(20, i*44+53, 280, 40);
            [followbutn setTitle:[followuparray objectAtIndex:count] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [followbutn addTarget:self action:@selector(followaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [followbutn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            followbutn.tag = count;
            [self.view addSubview:followbutn];
        }
        count++; 
    }

-(void)followaction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%d",button.tag);

    [followbutn viewWithTag:button.tag];
    [followbutn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

When I click on any button, that particular button must be checked and other buttons must not be checked. When I click on any button, only the button with the last tag checks in.

Can someone determine the issue?

Answer (score 2):

So basically you want to implement a checkbox?  You should create a subclass of `UIButton`.  Then add this line of code to the `UIViewController` or other container of the buttons.

`[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selfTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];`

and then add the following method to the container:

```
-(void)selfTapped{
 //CustomButton is the UIButton Subclass
 for(CustomButton *but in buttonArray){
  if(but.checked){
    but.checked = NO;
    [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  }else{
    but.checked = YES
    [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  }
 }
}
```

***Please let me know if you have any questions.***

Checked is a `BOOL`, and once, again, this method is within a subclass of `UIButton`, and the two images in this code are images displaying a checked and uncheck checkbox corresponding with the value of the `BOOL`.

EDIT: Please see my edits above in response to your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. But on tapping the botton the checked image just gets highlighted . i need the checked image to be on the button and the other buttons with unchecked images.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understood your question, I think you want your buttons to be working as radio button. 
For that give unique tag to each button unlike you tagged here with just one count var. 
Using that tag check your button by changing its image & remove tags of other buttons accept your checked one.And when you want to check other button initialize tags value again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your code....  run this loop till max tag value....

```
-(void)followaction:(id)sender
{
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[button viewWithTag:i];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    [button viewWithTag:button.tag];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: i already did this. This works fine. But i only want one button to checked in not the multiple selection.

Comment: thanks aloot Rajneesh i was able to solve the problem with ur help.